# How to use responsive.js in a theme derived from Luma?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, theme, css, rwd

The Magento [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_js.html) says

> You can use the menu.js, responsive.js and matchMedia.js to add
>   responsive behavior in your custom theme. If your theme inherits from
>   Blank or Luma, you do not even need to additionally include the script
>   files in your theme.

But what does this actually mean in practice? I need to alter some css classes/onclick behaviour based on the media query, but if I don't even need to additionally include the script files in my theme, how does it work?

Comment: I have tried placing a copy of responsive.js in my theme's web/js directory and it isn't picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing correct but need to do some more steps. Below, I have listed steps for it.

- First copy `responsive.js` file from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/` file and put it in your theme at `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/`.
- Now add your change in that `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/responsive.js` file.
- Now run cache flush command and then run setup static content deploy command.
- You can see your changes are reflecting.

As per Magento, you can add your own media match as added in that `responsive.js` file.

Here is one example of it. **You can change `media: '(min-width: 768px)'` code as per requirement.**

```
mediaCheck({
    media: '(min-width: 768px)',

    /**
     * Entry in the width.
     */
    entry: function () {
       put your code here when device screen width less then '768px'.  
    },

    /**
     * Exit from the width.
     */
    exit: function () {
       put your code here when device screen width more then '768px'.  
    }
});
```

Comment: No success I'm afraid.  But I'm suspecting there might be a locale issue.  My store is configured as en_GB and indeed this pub/static file is being served: ./frontend/Homespace/United/en_GB/Magento_Theme/js/responsive.js, which is the core Magento version.  My theme version is in pub/static as /frontend/Homespace/United/en_US/responsive.js but not served.  So that suggests some mismatch between the Magento Locale and how it treats my theme (which as far as I can find is locale neutral??)

Comment: @milesb okay remove files from `frontend/Homespace/United/en_GB/` and run with language `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`

Comment: Thanks, I appear to have that working now. Much appreciated. Will mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below file in your theme.

> **File**:- app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/web/js/responsive.js

```
  define([
    'jquery',
    'matchMedia',
    'mage/tabs',
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
     //Write your code here
});
```

if not reflects changes then hit below commands and check

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
```

Comment: Please see the comment to kunj's answer below